# how to apply content editor or script editor webpart for all list views?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Can we use content editor or script editor webpart for all list views. I don't find any option to apply single content editor to all list views.

Is there any possibility

Comment: You can add the script in master page, so it will run on all pages.

Comment: okay, so i have only option to edit master

Answer (score 0):

The answer is technically, one at a time. There isn't really a way to do that. As PS commented, you could add a content editor to the master page, but that's not going to run on just views of a particular list, it will run on all pages of the site including all views for all lists on the site. That's probably not a great solution if what you're trying to achieve is add something to all views of a particular list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply a content/script editor web part for all lists views.

If you want to apply the same code for all list views, you can add a condition to classify if the current page is a view page or not, then If it is a view page, add your code into the area. you can have a try.